# Add CSS class to php function WooCommerce variation dropdown

Tags: php, css, woocommerce, dropdown

In the following PHP function, I want to add a CSS class to the yellow marking (see the screenshot below):

[image]

Is there any solution?

I want to add a CSS class to move the price to the right.

--------------- PHP below ---------------

```
/**
 * Display price in variation options dropdown for products that have only one attribute.
 *
 * @param  string $term Existing option term value.
 * @return string $term Existing option term value or updated term value with price.
 */
function display_price_in_variation_options( $term ) {
    $product = wc_get_product();
    $id      = $product->get_id();
    if ( empty( $term ) || empty( $id ) ) {
        return $term;
    }
    if ( $product->is_type( 'variable' ) ) {
        $product_variations = $product->get_available_variations();
    } else {
        return $term;
    }
    foreach ( $product_variations as $variation ) {
        if ( count( $variation['attributes'] ) > 1 ) {
            return $term;
        }
        $attribute = array_values( $variation['attributes'] )[0];
        if ( $attribute === $term ) {
        $term .= ' (' . wp_strip_all_tags( wc_price ( $variation['display_price']) ) . ') ';      
        }
    }
    return $term;
}

add_filter( 'woocommerce_variation_option_name', 'display_price_in_variation_options' );




add_action( 'woocommerce_before_single_product', 'move_variations_single_price', 1 );
function move_variations_single_price(){
  global $product, $post;
  if ( $product->is_type( 'variable' ) ) {
    add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'replace_variation_single_price', 10 );
  }
}

function replace_variation_single_price() {
  ?>
    <style>
      .woocommerce-variation-price {
        display: none;
    
      }
    </style>
    <script>
      jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
        var priceselector = '.product p.price';
        var originalprice = $(priceselector).html();

        $( document ).on('show_variation', function() {
          $(priceselector).html($('.single_variation .woocommerce-variation-price').html());
        });
        $( document ).on('hide_variation', function() {
          $(priceselector).html(originalprice);
        });
      });
    </script>
  <?php
}
```

I have tried to add `<span class="">` with no result.

Comment: If this gets rendered as a native `select` element, then you can't do that. `option` elements allow only text content, you can not nest other HTML elements like span in there. You would need some sort of custom replacement then.